# Почему time.sleep() не срабатывает в цикле?

Tags: python, while

Пишу цикл while, почему-то не отрабатывает time.sleep(5) всё перепробовал но цикл выполняется с бешеной скоростью, примерно с такой:

```
16:13:33.182980 
16:13:33.446122 
16:13:33.716278 
16:13:34.005195 
16:13:34.296100 
16:13:34.587162 
16:13:34.864772
16:13:35.189284 
16:13:35.475026 
16:13:35.745385 
16:13:36.025683 
16:13:36.882705 
16:13:37.201377 
16:13:37.524670
```

как это можно исправить? Вот сам цикл:

```
while True:
    try:
        # Получаем таблицу на 4 часа
        bars_global = exchange.fetch_ohlcv('BTC-PERP', timeframe='4h', limit=100)
        df_global = pandas.DataFrame(bars_global[:-1],
                                     columns=['timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])
        # Находим значения ema на 4 часа
        global_ema_1 = float(df_global['close'].ewm(span=1).mean().tail(1))  # .tail(1)
        global_ema_11 = float(df_global['close'].ewm(span=11).mean().tail(1))

        # Получаем таблицу на 15 минут
        bars_local = exchange.fetch_ohlcv('BTC-PERP', timeframe='15m', limit=100)
        df_local = pandas.DataFrame(bars_local,
                                    columns=['timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])
        # Находим значения ema на 15 минут
        df_local['local_ema_1'] = df_local['close'].ewm(span=1).mean()
        df_local['local_ema_3'] = df_local['close'].ewm(span=3).mean()

        if db.contains(Base.side == 'long'):
            print(datetime.now().time(),
                  '\033[33mСЕЙЧАС ОТКРЫТА ПОЗИЦИЯ В ЛОНГ, ОЖИДАЕМ СИГНАЛ НА УСРЕДНЕНИЕ ИЛИ ЗАКРЫТИЕ\033[0m')
            # Проверяем pnl
            recentPnl = exchange.fetch_positions(
                params={'privateGetPositions': True})
            pnl = (recentPnl[0]['info']['recentPnl'])
            # Высчитываем необходимый профит
            profit = (amount / 100) * profit_percent
            if pnl >= profit:
                # Закрываем лонг
                amount_size = float('{}'.format(amount))
                position = exchange.create_order(symbol=symbol, type='market',
                                                 side='sell',
                                                 amount=amount_size)
                # Очищаем БД
                db.truncate()
                db.all()
                # Удаляем таблицу
                db.drop_table('price')

            elif pnl <= -profit:
                # Берём цену открытия позиции из БД
                price = db.table('price')
                new_price = (price.all()[0]['price'])
                # Считаем цену следующей усредняйки
                price_now = new_price * logarithm
                if new_price <= price_now * logarithm:
                    # Удаляем старую таблицу в БД
                    db.drop_table('price')
                    # Усредняем с учётом мартина и логарифма
                    new_amount = amount * martin
                    amount_size = float('{}'.format(new_amount))
                    position = exchange.create_order(symbol=symbol, type='market',
                                                     side='buy',
                                                     amount=amount_size)
                    # # Узнаём цену входа в позицию
                    recentPrice = exchange.fetch_positions(
                        params={'privateGetPositions': True})
                    entryPrice = (recentPrice[0]['info']['entryPrice'])
                    # Создаём новую таблицу в БД
                    price = db.table('price')
                    # Записываем в таблицу БД
                    price.insert({'price': entryPrice})

        elif db.contains(Base.side == 'short'):
            print(datetime.now().time(),
                  '\033[33mСЕЙЧАС ОТКРЫТА ПОЗИЦИЯ В ШОРТ, ОЖИДАЕМ СИГНАЛ НА УСРЕДНЕНИЕ ИЛИ ЗАКРЫТИЕ\033[0m')
            # Проверяем pnl
            recentPnl = exchange.fetch_positions(
                params={'privateGetPositions': True})
            pnl = (recentPnl[0]['info']['recentPnl'])
            # Высчитываем необходимый профит
            profit = (amount / 100) * profit_percent
            if pnl >= profit:
                # Закрываем шорт
                amount_size = float('{}'.format(amount))
                position = exchange.create_order(symbol=symbol, type='market',
                                                 side='buy',
                                                 amount=amount_size)
                # Очищаем БД
                db.truncate()
                db.all()
                # Удаляем таблицу
                db.drop_table('price')

            elif pnl <= -profit:
                # Берём цену открытия позиции из БД
                price = db.table('price')
                new_price = (price.all()[0]['price'])
                # Считаем цену следующей усредняйки
                price_now = new_price * logarithm
                if new_price >= price_now * logarithm:
                    # Удаляем старую таблицу в БД
                    db.drop_table('price')
                    # Усредняем с учётом мартина и логарифма
                    new_amount = amount * martin
                    amount_size = float('{}'.format(new_amount))
                    position = exchange.create_order(symbol=symbol, type='market',
                                                     side='sell',
                                                     amount=amount_size)
                    # # Узнаём цену входа в позицию
                    recentPrice = exchange.fetch_positions(
                        params={'privateGetPositions': True})
                    entryPrice = (recentPrice[0]['info']['entryPrice'])
                    # Создаём новую таблицу в БД
                    price = db.table('price')
                    # Записываем в таблицу БД
                    price.insert({'price': entryPrice})

        else:
            if global_ema_1 > global_ema_11:
                print(datetime.now().time(),
                      '\033[33mГЛОБАЛЬНЫЙ ТРЕНД - ЛОНГ, БОТ ОЖИДАЕТ НОВЫЕ СИГНАЛЫ ИНДИКАТОРОВ ДЛЯ ВХОДА\033[0m')

                if df_local['local_ema_1'][:-1] > df_local['local_ema_3'][:-1] and df_local['local_ema_1'][:-2] > df_local['local_ema_3'][:-2]:

                    # Открываем позицию в лонг
                    amount_size = float('{}'.format(amount))
                    position = exchange.create_order(symbol=symbol, type='market',
                                                     side='buy',
                                                     amount=amount_size)
                    db.insert({'side': 'long'})
                    # Узнаём цену входа в позицию
                    recentPrice = exchange.fetch_positions(
                        params={'privateGetPositions': True})
                    entryPrice = (recentPrice[0]['info']['entryPrice'])
                    # Создаём новую таблицу в БД
                    price = db.table('price')
                    # Записываем её в таблицу
                    price.insert({'price': entryPrice})
                    # Отправляем оповещалки
                     print(
                        '\033[96m######## БОT ОТКРЫЛ ПОЗИЦИЮ В ЛОНГ ПО СИГНАЛУ ИНДИКАТОРОВ #########\033[0m')
                    
            elif global_ema_1 < global_ema_11:

                print(datetime.now().time(),
                      '\033[33mГЛОБАЛЬНЫЙ ТРЕНД - ШОРТ, БОТ ОЖИДАЕТ НОВЫЕ СИГНАЛЫ ИНДИКАТОРОВ ДЛЯ ВХОДА\033[0m')

                if df_local['local_ema_1'][:-1] < df_local['local_ema_3'][:-1] and df_local['local_ema_1'][:-2] > df_local['local_ema_3'][:-2]:

                    # Открываем позицию в шорт
                    amount_size = float('{}'.format(amount))
                    position = exchange.create_order(symbol=symbol, type='market',
                                                     side='sell',
                                                     amount=amount_size)
                    db.insert({'side': 'short'})
                    # Узнаём цену входа в позицию
                    recentPrice = exchange.fetch_positions(
                        params={'privateGetPositions': True})
                    entryPrice = (recentPrice[0]['info']['entryPrice'])
                    # Создаём новую таблицу в БД
                    price = db.table('price')
                    # Записываем её в таблицу
                    price.insert({'price': entryPrice})
                    # Отправляем оповещалки
                    print(
                        '\033[96m######## БОТ ОТКРЫЛ ПОЗИЦИЮ В ШОРТ ПО СИГНАЛУ ИНДИКАТОРОВ #########\033[0m')
                   
    except (Exception,):
        continue
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Видимо потому что вместо него выполняется `except (Exception,): continue`

Comment: спасибо это помогло, убрав try-except сразу нашёл ошибку  The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). в  155 и 184 строчках, после чего заменил if df_local['local_ema_1'][:-1] > df_local['local_ema_3'][:-1] and df_local['local_ema_1'][:-2] > df_local['local_ema_3'][:-2]: на if df_local['local_ema_1'].to_numpy()[-1] < df_local['local_ema_3'].to_numpy()[-1] and df_local['local_ema_1'].to_numpy()[-2] > df_local['local_ema_3'].to_numpy()[-2]: теперь всё работает

Comment: На будущее запомните, что "глотать" исключения - очень плохая практика. Если хотите пропустить конкретное исключение - ловите только его (а не обобщённое `Exception`), и в любом случае как-то логируйте исключение выводом на экран или в лог.

Comment: Зачем такой большой блок отлова исключений? оставьте только там, где они могут возникнуть не по вашей вине.
Никогда не падающий код - это тот еще баттхерд

Answer (score 0):

Слип не срабатывает, если в блоке try выкидывает исключение.